# What causes "The connection was reset" error message?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, torcheck, tor-cloud

I need to log in to this website: www.mercadolivre.com.br in my country (enter is entrar, in top of this page have link ENTRAR), but it doesn't load the page in Tor.

I received this message: "The connection was reset. The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading."

Any idea what causes this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, with slow sites, loading the page takes so long that the connection is reset. Sometimes it works simply by trying again. There could also be a problem with loading data from other hosts. You could check the 'Developer Console' in your browser.

Comment: I think this site block Tor, is possible this ?

Comment: Everything is possible.